# Getting product positions in Shopify smartCollection

Tags: shopify

I want to use a recent API version (at least 2020-07) to retrieve the positions of products in smartCollections.

When I directly query the collect endpoint with the oldest supported stable API:

```
/admin/collects.json?collection_id=1234567
```

I receive the collect entities as one would expect.

When I run it against a newer version of the API:

```
/admin/api/2020-07/collects.json?collection_id=1234567
```

I get a 404 error: **Cannot load Collects belonging to a SmartCollection**.

**So my question is:** how do I get the positions of products in a smartCollection using a current API version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying the products of a smartCollection will return the products in the order that you can see them in the shopify backend. So there is no need at all to use the collects to get the positions:

```
/admin/api/2020-07/collection/1234567/products.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you get positions in a Smart Collection as it triggers off of rules. So if you were to manually place items in position, it would make sense as a rule change would inject or remove products ruining the positioning. I think collect positions only matter to manual collections.

Comment: Hmmm - I am not sure about that. You can set order of a smartCollection to manual and I think in this case new items that are added by rules and which have not been positioned manually are attached to the end of the collection. At least I am getting results with the "old" API.

Comment: Whatever, they are scrapping collects anyway, so you're probably in that lala land between the time the new collection code and old collection code is in place.

Comment: OK, interesting, thank you for that insight. Do you by any chance have a link where I can read more about the collects being scrapped?

Comment: Some of my forum posts point out problems with collections, and when Shopify chimed in, they revealed that. So the usual thing in play. The OLD RestAPI may still work, and if the new GraphQL does not, it is likely due to the fact they are not supporting that operation anymore, so best you work around it. Sticking with old RestAPI to get something done will ensure one day soon you get a notice to stop using an unsupported feature. Best guess anyway...

Comment: Point is, if you use the GQL to built a collection, you realize it is not actually built for N seconds later. No method exists to query this process. So Shopify revealed it was a problem of assigning the Collects, and that they now understand this is a clunky mechanism, and needs replacement. So it is being replaced. We just do not know exactly when they get that together in terms of the GQL and reality of production Shopify.

Comment: Thanks again for your insight. Yes, I am very hesitant  to use the "old" API for the reasons you cite, could be turned off any time and then all the work was for nothing.

Comment: @DavidLazar .. anyway I can reach out to you. Looking for some guidance in resolving something related to Shopify.